# Where is the HiDPI option in Linux mint 17 "mate"

Tags: linux-mint, retina, mate

I installed Linux mint 17 mate in my Macbook pro retina with Virtual box, but the font is very small, how do I enable the HiDPI option in mate?

Comment: You might have more luck asking this question on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

HiDPI is not supported by MATE yet. Maybe Gnome environment is a better alternative for you.

Answer (score 0):

For now HiDPI on Linux Mint is supported only on Cinnamon.